# How to create a function or operator using a symbol?

Tags: r, function

I would like to create a function with a symbol (for instance, `~`), which works similarly to the  "question mark" function.

Comment: ``R> `?` = c; R> `?`(3, 5)`` so for `~` you could do something like ``R> `~` = c;
R> 3 ~ 5
[1] 3 5``. This is a pretty general question. look at `?` surrounded by backticks (i cant figure out how to get it surrounded by backticks with the formatting here) to see how its defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do something as "bare" as `?foo` without messing with the C code that defines the syntax of R. For example, you can't make `[fnord` be meaningful.

This comes from the syntax definition in gram.y in the R sources.

```
|   '~' expr %prec TILDE        { $$ = xxunary($1,$2); }
|   '?' expr            { $$ = xxunary($1,$2); }

|   expr ':'  expr          { $$ = xxbinary($2,$1,$3); }
|   expr '+'  expr          { $$ = xxbinary($2,$1,$3); }
```

The second line above defines the syntax for `?foo`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a fast way to access a cache environment that I created. For instance by programming the function '_', _myVariable could return getEnv("myVariable", envir="myCacheEnv")

Answer (score 2):

You can make functions and variables with arbitrary names, via use of the backtick `.

```
`~` <- `+`
y <- 5
x <- 10
y ~ x
# 15
```

I wouldn't mess with `~` though, unless you don't intend to do any statistical modelling....

Comment: Messing with `~` looks a bit scary!

Comment: good point, ~ is certainly not the best character to use. Almost all characters are already taken though. I was thinking that with S4 class we could have a dispatching that differenciates e1~e2 and ~e2